# Present UINavigationController and show additional (second) title above navigation bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I wonder if it is possible to show additional title above navigation bar like it is done in iOS7 WiFi settings (Other Network) - Enter network information.

[image]

This is how I present my navigation controller:

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I was looking for a solution but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`prompt`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/prompt) of the view controller's `navigationItem`:

```
UIViewController *vc = [UIViewController new];
vc.navigationItem.prompt = @"Enter network information";
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

[image: Example]